# Cannot find the declaration of element 'XML_Element' under C++Builder

Tags: c++builder, indy, xmldocument

I am facing an error "HTTP/1.1 400" after XML parsing error with message "Cannot find the declaration of element 'XML_Element'".
The posts I found in the web about the subject didn't help so any comment about my below code will be really appreciated.

File .cpp

```
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{Button1->Cursor = crHourGlass;

 int IX0BBClick = 0;

 _di_IXMLDocument XMLDocument1 = interface_cast<Xmlintf::IXMLDocument> (new TXMLDocument(NULL));
 _di_IXMLDocument XMLDocument2 = interface_cast<Xmlintf::IXMLDocument> (new TXMLDocument(NULL));

 UnicodeString US0Reponse, US0URl = "http://Marin-ml.ubiMarin-senegal.com";

try {//- Document XML #1 = Demande|Request
     XMLDocument1->Active = true;
     XMLDocument1->Version = "1.0";
     XMLDocument1->Encoding = "UTF-8";
     XMLDocument1->Options = XMLDocument1->Options <<doNodeAutoIndent >>doNamespaceDecl >>doAutoPrefix;

        //- DMC_WRAPPER
        _di_IXMLNode XN0Wrapper = XMLDocument1->CreateNode("DMC_WRAPPER");
        XMLDocument1->SetDocumentElement(XN0Wrapper);
        XMLDocument1->DocumentElement->DeclareNamespace("", "urn:x-srp:fr.srp.protocole:enveloppe-v30");
        XMLDocument1->DocumentElement->DeclareNamespace("xsi", "https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

            //- BODY under DMC_WRAPPER
            _di_IXMLNode XN0WBody = XMLDocument1->DocumentElement->AddChild("BODY", "urn:x-srp:fr.srp.protocole:enveloppe-v30");

                    //- SHIP_MESSAGE
                _di_IXMLNode XN0WBMShip = XN0WBody->AddChild("SHIP_MESSAGE", "urn:x-srp:fr.srp.protocole:message-v30");
                if(XN0WBMShip)
                    {
                    //\ SHIP_MESSAGE
            //\ BODY under DMC_WRAPPER
        //\ DMC_WRAPPER
     //- Document XML #1 = Demande|Request

                     TIdHTTP *IdHTTP1 = new TIdHTTP(this);
                     TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL *LHandler = new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(this);
                     IdHTTP1->IOHandler = LHandler;

                     TIdHashMessageDigest5 *MD5Digest = new TIdHashMessageDigest5;
                     UnicodeString UX0Content_MarinaML = XMLDocument1->XML->Text + "MySecretData";
                     UX0Content_MarinaML = MD5Digest->HashStringAsHex(UX0Content_MarinaML);
                    
                     //- Initialisation HTTP
                     IdHTTP1->Request->CustomHeaders->AddValue("Content-MarinML", UX0Content_MarinML);
                     IdHTTP1->Request->CustomHeaders->AddValue("Version-MarinML", "3.0.0.0");
                     IdHTTP1->Request->CustomHeaders->AddValue("Origin", "http://myurl.com");
                     IdHTTP1->Request->UserAgent      = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100102 Firefox/12.0";
                     IdHTTP1->Request->Accept         = "*/*";
                     IdHTTP1->Request->AcceptLanguage = "en-US,en;q=0.8";
                     IdHTTP1->Request->ContentType    = "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
                     //\ Initialisation HTTP

                     XMLDocument1->SaveToFile(Form1->UX0CPDOrthassis + "\\MEDMAR00.xml");
                     TStringStream *SS0REBody = new TStringStream(XMLDocument1->XML->Text);
                     TMemoryStream *MS0Response = new TMemoryStream();

                     IdLogStream1 = new TIdLogStream(NULL); // Débogage | Debugging
                     IdLogStream1->ReceiveStream = new TStringStream(); // Débogage | Debugging
                     IdLogStream1->FreeStreams = true; // Débogage | Debugging
                     IdLogStream1->Active = true; // Débogage | Debugging
                     IdLogStream1->ReplaceCRLF = false; // Débogage | Debugging
                     IdHTTP1->Intercept = IdLogStream1; // Débogage | Debugging
                     RichEdit1->Clear(); // Débogage | Debugging

                     //\ Exécution requête HTTP
                     IdHTTP1->Post(US0URl, SS0REBody, MS0Response);
                     //- Exécution requête HTTP

                     //- Document XML #2 = Réponse|Response
                     XMLDocument2->LoadFromStream(MS0Response);
                     //\ Document XML #2 = Réponse|Response

                     RichEdit1->Clear();
                     RichEdit1->Lines->Add(XMLDocument1->XML->Text);
                     RichEdit1->Lines->Add("//-------------------");

                     RichEdit2->Clear();
                     RichEdit2->Lines->Add(XMLDocument2->XML->Text);
                     RichEdit2->Lines->Add("//-------------------");
                    }
                else
                    {XMLDocument1->XML->Text = "XN0WBMShip not assigned!";
                    }

      XMLDocument2->SaveToFile(Form1->UX0CPDOrthassis + "\\MERMAR00.xml");

      IX0BBClick = 1;
    }
 catch(EIdHTTPProtocolException &EX0Vl){IdLogStream1->ReceiveStream->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
                                        RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(IdLogStream1->ReceiveStream);
                                        Form1->AX0LMes = RichEdit1->Lines->Text;
                                        Form1->IKAf0ORTErr();
                                       }
 catch(ERemotableException &EX0Vl){Form1->AX0LMes = EX0Vl.Message; Form1->IKAf0ORTErr();}
 catch(EDatabaseError &EX0Vl) {Form1->AX0LMes = EX0Vl.Message; Form1->IKAf0ORTErr();}
 catch(Exception &EX0Vl) {Form1->AX0LMes = EX0Vl.Message; Form1->IKAf0ORTErr();}
 catch(...) {Form1->AX0LMes = "Exception non gérée."; Form1->IKAf0ORTErr();}

 Button1->Cursor = crDefault;
}
```

Sent message : MEDMAR00.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DMC_WRAPPER xmlns="urn:x-srp:fr.srp.protocole:enveloppe-v30" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <BODY>
    <SHIP_MESSAGE xmlns="urn:x-srp:fr.srp.protocole:message-v30"/>
  </BODY>
</DMC_WRAPPER>
```

Error log : IdLogStream1->ReceiveStream

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 â€“ Bad 
Request</title><style type="text/css">body {font-
family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-
color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-
size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line 
{height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head>
<body><h1>HTTP Status 400 â€“ Bad Request</h1><hr class="line" />
<p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Erreur : 
[DMCRequest] Erreur de parsing XML pour la requÃªte DMCÂ : Error on 
line 2: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element &#
39;DMC_WRAPPER&#39;.
Message MarinaML = [&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;?&gt;
&lt;DMC_WRAPPER xmlns=&quot;urn:x-srp:fr.srp.protocole:enveloppe-
v30&quot; xmlns:xsi=&quot;https:&#47;&#47;www.w3.org&#47;2001&#
47;XMLSchema-instance&quot;&gt;
  &lt;BODY&gt;
    &lt;SHIP_MESSAGE xmlns=&quot;urn:x-
srp:fr.srp.protocole:message-v30&quot;&#47;&gt;
  &lt;&#47;BODY&gt;
&lt;&#47;DMC_WRAPPER&gt;
]</p><p><b>Description</b> The server cannot or will not process the 
request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., 
malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive 
request routing).</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.56
</h3></body></html>
<!--
2024/02/13 - 10:33:28, TEMarinaml/1219001 : HTTP/1.1 400 
Server: nginx/1.7.6
Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2024 10:33:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1330
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: en
-->
```

Comment: There is no mention of `XML_Element` anywhere in the code or error message. The error message is actually claiming that is can't find the `DMC_WRAPPER` element in the XML you are sending. You are putting namespaces in the XML, that may be related. Are you sure the server is expecting the `DMC_WRAPPER` element to be in a namespace? Have you tried removing the namespaces? Also, I do see a number of other issues in this code that could be improved.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you for your comment. You are right, 'DMC_WRAPPER' is replaced by 'XML_Element' in the title.
Yes, putting 'DMC_WRAPPER' in namespaces is the recommendation. I verified, removing them doesn't change the issue.
When the Error log is sent to a browser some '/' are still displayed as '&# 47;' so 'xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' results in 'xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001&# 47;XMLSchema-instance"'. May this be the cause of the problem ?

Comment: That is not the problem. `TIdHTTP::Post()` transmits `TStream` data as-is (the same `Intercept` with a `SendStream` assigned can show you that). So either you are sending the wrong XML to begin with, or the XML is not being processed correctly on the server side. You need to talk with the server admin about this issue. Don't worry about the way the XML is encoded in the response error, that is simply because the XML is embedded inside of HTML. That doesn't affect the XML itself.

Comment: That being said, the non-XML issues I see: 1) `interface_cast<Xmlintf::IXMLDocument> (new TXMLDocument(NULL))` should be replaced with `NewXMLDocument()`; 2) You are leaking `MD5Digest`, `SS0REBody`, `MS0Response`, and `IdLogStream1`; 3) `HashStringAsHex()` needs `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8`, and `new TStringStream(XMLDocument1->XML->Text)` needs `TEncoding::UTF8`; 4) When handling `EIdHTTPProtocolException`, the correct place to get the response data is from the exception's `ErrorMessage` property.

Comment: Thank you so much @RemyLebeau ! While waiting to solve the XML issue, I will improve my code.